# How to create POM Appium Python

Tags: python, android, mobile, appium

I have problems creating conftest file and and connecting to other files flows, actions, test_suits, locators. Please help me, i couldnt find solution from other sources. i need beginning step of POM of appium python, Can you suggest any sources that i can find solution to this question or share code structures

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-> conftest.py (root) -> base fixtures(init appium_driver, addopts, etc)
-> pytest.ini
  -> packages -> TestCase -> base_test.py -> class BaseTest extend appium_driver                     
              -> PageObjects -> class BaseScreen -> class LoginScreen
                                                      -> Locators and actions with page
              -> Utilities
              -> etc.
```

Comment: [base framework structure](https://github.com/DimaBerezovskyi/python-appium-tricks/tree/main/trick_3)